# Eloquent get user with highest relation table points

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the user with the highest evaluation points based on charisma and persuasion

What i have wrote so far after this i couldn't figure out how to make it work

```
    $user = User::where('commision_id', $data['commision'])->whereHas('role', function ($q) {
        $q->where('level', 2);
    })->with(['evaluations' => function ($q) {
        
    }]);
```

The evaluations relation migration

```
    Schema::create('evaluations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->boolean('charisma')->default(false); 
        $table->boolean('persuasion')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('politics')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('heat')->default(false);
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('hl')->nullable();
        $table->integer('exp')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->index('user_id');
    });
```

So basically i have to sum the exp points based on persuasion and the exp points based on charisma then sum both of those sum values to get the highest ranking user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add up those 2 properties on the fly and simply get the one with the highest attribute.

```
$user = User::where('commision_id', $data['commision'])->whereHas('role', function ($q) {
    $q->where('level', 2);
})->with(['evaluations'])
->get()
->each(function ($u) { 
    $u->score = $u->evaluations->charisma + $u->evaluations->persuasion
});

$topUser = $user->orderBy('score')->first();
```

In case one user can have many evaluations, you would do the similar thing:

```
->each(function ($u) { 
     $u->score = null;
     $charisma  = $u->evaluations->pluck('charisma')->sum();
     $persuasion = = $u->evaluations->pluck('persuasion')->sum();
     $u->score += $charisma;
     $u->score += $persuasion ;
 });
```

Comment: The code won't be functional as `charisma` and `persuasian` are properties on `evaluations` and not the user, so the each function will fail.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can access it the same way you would from anywhere elsewhere in the application, given that you have appropriate relationship set in User model.

Comment: Charisma and Persuasion are boolean values, the value which should be calculated is the exp, so there must be an if statement which checks if the charisma or persuasion is true and calculate the exp. User has many evaluations. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: You can still do the same thing and just use ->filter() after pluck, like $u->evaluations->pluck('persuasion')->filter()->sum();

Comment: I have to do something like this $persuasion = $u->evaluations->pluck('persuasion', 'exp'); and sum the exp where the persuasion boolean value is true.

Answer (score 0):

What made it work is using filter function to filter the boolean values of Charisma and Persuasion, thanks to N L which pointed me to the right direction, i accepted his answer.

```
    $user = User::where('commision_id', $data['commision'])->whereHas('role', function ($q) {
        $q->where('level', 2);
    })->with(['evaluations'])
    ->get()
    ->each(function ($u) { 
        $u->score = null;
        
        $charisma  = $u->evaluations->filter(function($value) {
            return $value->charisma == true;
        })->sum('exp');

        $persuasion = $u->evaluations->filter(function($value) {
            return $value->persuasion == true;
        })->sum('exp');
        
        $u->score += $charisma;
        $u->score += $persuasion;
    })->sortByDesc('score')->first();
```